# How to make haproxy wait for a port 61313?

Tags: cloud

I'm doing an OpenStack deployment with kolla-ansible. And running the command ***`**kolla-ansible -i ./all-in-one deploy**`*** I get the following error described also in the image above:

RUNNING HANDLER [loadbalancer : Wait for master haproxy to start] *************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "elapsed": 300, "msg": "Timeout when waiting for 10.30.1.148:61313"}

Deploying OpenStack with Kolla-ansible